# modal dialog box in mvc.net using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC.Net and jQuery. I want to open another page in modal dialog box and after closing the dialog box it return some value to parent page.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jQuery UI [Dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). It allows to handle button clicks and dialog closing.

Comment: i have already seen that but my problem is open anather page there he is openeing showing content of same page like Div. if u provide me sode thenit will be very helpfull

Comment: What browser are you using. It may be a z-order thing; this occurs, for example, with earlier versions of IE.